# WCF iis 7 error

Tags: wcf, iis-7, iis-6

I am getting the following error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

I was not getting this error on IIS 6

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS 6 allows the wcf application to run with bindings of http alone.

IIS 7 gives this error. I had to add a dummy certificate to the IIS 7 configuration to get it to work.